# Having difficulty in implementing QuickSort

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I have been trying to implement quicksort for like 2 days now  (Looks like my programming skills are getting rusty). I do not know what I am doing wrong. I was  about to give up so I thought I should consult the discussion forum.

here is the code that I am trying to implement in python. But it is not giving the desired result.  Anyone can please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
def QuickSort(A,p,r):

if p < r:
    pivotIndex = Partition(A,p,r)
    QuickSort(A,p,pivotIndex-1)
    QuickSort(A,pivotIndex+1,r)
    return A
def Partition(A,p,r):

m = A[p]
i = p+1
for j in range( p+1 , r ):
    if A[j] < m:
        A[j] , A[i] = A[i] , A[j]
        i+=1
A[p], A[i-1] = A[i-1] , A[p]
return i-1
```

The output for test input is:

```
>>>QuickSort([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],0,9)
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2, 9]
```

I will be very thankful if anyone help me in implementing this.

Regards

Comment: `QuickSort(A[0:pivotIndex])` will already exclude the `pivotIndex`, so I don't think you need to subtract 1.

Comment: I have done this, but still I am getting the same result :/

Comment: Your single-letter naming scheme is unnecessarily difficult to decipher. If you used more informative names, it'd be easier for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. It appeared that I was passing one-less to the QuickSort method

```
def QuickSort(A,p,r):
    if r-p <= 1: return
    pivotIndex = Partition(A,p,r)
    QuickSort(A,p,pivotIndex)
    QuickSort(A,pivotIndex+1,r)
    return A
def Partition(A,p,r):

    m = A[p]
    i = p+1

    for j in range( p+1 , r ):
        if A[j] < m:
            A[j] , A[i] = A[i] , A[j]
        i= i + 1
    A[p], A[i-1] = A[i-1] , A[p]
    return i-1
```

It is the correct implementation

Comment: I am getting this [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 2):

Slicing doesn't return a view of the original list; it makes a new list out of data from the old list. That means the recursive calls to `QuickSort` don't change the original list.

Comment: Have your functions take indices to sort between instead of slicing the list.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I want to do it the same way. Can you suggest any other way so that I can only pass one argument to the function(that is list) ?

Comment: Python comes with no way to take a sublist view of a list. This was probably considered too error-prone and not useful enough. If you really want to, you could write a complete implementation of such an object yourself, then pass those around, but it would be way more code than just passing indices around.

Comment: @InspiredCoder: If you want to pass only one argument, pass a tuple.

Comment: You could write a helper method that would take a second argument. That way the initial function only has the one argument.

Comment: Please check the main thread again. I have updated it with index arguments. Still I am unable to get it to work properly.

Comment: You have off-by-one errors. Check your bounds. Bill the Lizard's comment is useful.

Comment: Thanks I have figured out  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this implementation in one line of code:

```
def QuickSort(list):
    return [] if list==[]  else QuickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x < list[0]]) + [list[0]] + QuickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x >= list[0]])

print QuickSort([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

Comment: This algorithm has average complexity O(n^2), while Quicksort has O(n log n). In addition, memory overhead is O(n) instead of O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wanted to keep the pivot on the left side and skip it, but that didn't turn out well, so I just moved it to the end of the array and reduced the iteration index accordingly and then reversed the post-partition swap (to take into consideration the pivot movement).

```
def Partition(A,p,r):

  m = A[p]
  A[p], A[r] = A[r], A[p]
  i = p
  for j in range( p, r ):
    if A[j] < m:
        A[j] , A[i] = A[i] , A[j]
        i+=1
  A[r], A[i] = A[i] , A[r]
  return i
```

I think that you could do it with the pivot on the left side, but then you would have to change the loop direction I guess, but I am not sure.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to add the call is then QuickSort([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],0,**8**), since the indices are inclusive now.